# Why can you use open() as context manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

From Python's [source code of **`open`**](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Tools/freeze/bkfile.py), I think `open` is just a normal function.

Why can  we use it like below?

```
with open('what_are_context_managers.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print('> {}'.format(line))
```

Since is neither implements `__enter__` nor `__exit__`, nor uses `contextlib.contextmanager` decorator.

Comment: The original `file` type that is returned by the function implements the context manager interface.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are not using the `open` function as a context manager. It is the *result of the `open(...)` call expression* that is the context manager. `open()` returns a file object, and it is that object that has `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods; see the [`io.IOBase` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase):

> *IOBase* is also a context manager and therefore supports the with statement.

You can read the `with` statement like this:

```
_context_manager = open('what_are_context_managers.txt', 'r')
with _context_manager as infile:
```

Note that it is the return value of `_context_manager.__enter__()` that ends up being assigned to `infile` here. For file objects, `file.__enter__()` returns `self`, so you can get access to the same object that way.

---

As a side-note; you got the wrong `open()` function. The actual definition of the `open()` built-in is an alias for [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.open), see the [`_iomodule.c` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Modules/_io/_iomodule.c#L95-L494). The alias is set in [`initstdio()` in `pylifecycle.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Python/pylifecycle.c#L1207-L1219) (where `io.OpenWrapper` is [itself an alias for `_io.open`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/io.py#L59)). And yes, the documentation states the alias points the other way for end-user ease.